# 'ld' Error while compiling a module (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, rust, cmake

I am trying to compile a module https://github.com/In-line/grip

I have installed the below tools

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y gcc-multilib g++-multilib
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
sudo apt-get install -y libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386
sudo apt-get install -y cmake
```

I am getting the below error

```
root@test:/home/ubuntu/grip# make
/usr/bin/cmake -S/home/ubuntu/grip -B/home/ubuntu/grip --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/ubuntu/grip/CMakeFiles /home/ubuntu/grip//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/grip'
make  -f rust/CMakeFiles/grip-rust_target.dir/build.make rust/CMakeFiles/grip-rust_target.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/grip'
cd /home/ubuntu/grip && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/ubuntu/grip /home/ubuntu/grip/rust /home/ubuntu/grip /home/ubuntu/grip/rust /home/ubuntu/grip/rust/CMakeFiles/grip-rust_target.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/grip'
make  -f rust/CMakeFiles/grip-rust_target.dir/build.make rust/CMakeFiles/grip-rust_target.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/grip'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'rust/CMakeFiles/grip-rust_target.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/grip'
[ 25%] Built target grip-rust_target
make  -f CMakeFiles/grip.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/grip.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/grip'
cd /home/ubuntu/grip && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/ubuntu/grip /home/ubuntu/grip /home/ubuntu/grip /home/ubuntu/grip /home/ubuntu/grip/CMakeFiles/grip.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/grip'
make  -f CMakeFiles/grip.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/grip.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/grip'
[ 50%] Linking CXX shared library grip_amxx_i386.so
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/grip.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC  -Wall -Wextra -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant -Wunknown-pragmas -m32 -O3 -mtune=generic -fvisibility=hidden -flto -fPIC -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--version-script=/home/ubuntu/grip/version_script.lds -fuse-ld=lld -shared -Wl,-soname,grip_amxx_i386.so -o grip_amxx_i386.so CMakeFiles/grip.dir/cpp/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/grip.dir/third_party/amxmodx/public/sdk/amxxmodule.cpp.o  rust/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/libgrip_rust.a -lpthread
collect2: fatal error: cannot find ‘ld’
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/grip.dir/build.make:117: grip_amxx_i386.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/grip'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: CMakeFiles/grip.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/grip'
make: *** [Makefile:94: all] Error 2
root@test:/home/ubuntu/grip#
```

which ld output

```
root@test:/home/ubuntu/grip# which ld
/usr/bin/ld
```

echo $PATH output

```
/root/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin
```

Can someone please help to solve this. I tried searching the web but couldn't get anything relevant.

Comment: Maybe you need to tweak one of the files in grip to force `/usr/bin/ld`.

Comment: @user4581301 can you tell me which file I need to tweak?

Comment: root@test:/home/ubuntu/grip# cat CMakeCache.txt | grep '/bin/ld'
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ld

Comment: I got the entry in one file CMakeCache.txt but the path is correct over there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of my friend suggested to do

```
apt install lld
```

and the issue got resolved.